# Django objects.all() empty query set, not empty in shell

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-ec2

I have been using Django for the past 2 years with no issues at all, I am no rookie.

I recently created a new attribute for a model and added it to the mysql database.

Whenever I filter things using this attribute in my "views.py" i get an empty set, whenever I use the same exact line of code using "manage.py shell" it returns the expected queryset.

I have tried restarting the httpd service, the mysqld service and I have rebooted the system but nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to bypass this issue?

Here's the code I used to debug this issue:

Shell:
It won't let me post pictures so here's the code:

```
>>>Session.objects.filter(cancellation_session=True)
>>>[<Session: Zumba Toning (Ladies)>]
```

views.py:

```
def gym_day2(request):
    return HttpResponse(str(Session.objects.filter(cancellation_session=True)))
```

HttpResponse:

```
[]
```

Please Help!

Comment: Which version of Django are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add . values or .values_list() after the statement , Session.objects.filter(cancellation_session=True).values(´field´)

Comment: It worked, but I need a logical explanation here. Because otherwise I'm switching career.

Comment: when using the ORM and want to get a filter value you need to add values_list () or values (), but in both cases you have earned the right query, for example you can use "session = Session.objects.filter (cancellation_session = True)" like an instance of another query "otro_query = sub_session.objects.filter (idsession = session)" and it works